# Generate compiler warning when certain values are supplied to parameters

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, compiler-warnings, .net-standard

I'm writing a public method in C# which does certain non-performant checks (for security reasons).

```cs
public bool CheckThing(int a, int b, bool secureCheck = true)
{
    if (secureCheck)
    {
        // do this thing slowly but safely
    }
    else
    {
        // do this as fast as possible
    }
    // ...
}
```

On occasion it might be unnecessary to do things the "slow" way, and I would like to let people in my team who know what they are doing set the `secureCheck` value to `false`.

What I would like to accomplish is have this method throw a "compiler warning" at the line that calls this method whenever the `secureCheck` value is set to `false` (and not if it's set to true). That way, team members who know what they are doing can acknowledge the warning by using a `#pragma` preprocessor directive:

```cs
#pragma warning disable InsecureCheckWarning // This call was checked by the team lead and is okay
var result = CheckThing(a, b, secureCheck: false)
#pragma warning restore InsecureCheckWarning
```

Is this possible (possibly using Roslyn)? If so, how would I achieve something like this?

For reference, this is a .NET Standard 2.0 library (and while C# 7.3 is currently being used I'm not opposed to using C# 8.0 if needed).

Comment: If you don't want to go with a full-blown code-analyzer for this, you can introduce a custom `struct SecureCheckFlag` that will wrap your `bool` value (plus implicit conversion back to `bool`, for easier use), have its constructor set to `private` and introduce both `public static SecureCheckFlag True` and `public static SecureCheckFlag False`, when the latter is marked with `[Obsolete("Your warning")]`

Comment: No point really making the constructor of the `struct` private. You can't have an explicit parameterless constructor, so assuming the constructor took a bool argument, you'd still be able to new up an instance which used the implicit parameterless one. That variant would obviously set a default false value for the flag. May as well make the constructor public

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to achieve this with Roslyn. I would create two analyzers:

1. Look at all invocations to `CheckThing()`. If someone calls this method and provides a variable (instead of a literal `True` or `False`) for `secureCheck` then your analyzer would throw an error.
2. Look at all invocations to `CheckThing()`. If someone passes in `False` then throw the warning you've described in your question.

The reason you need the first analyzer is to avoid situations where a static analyzer could not determine what value is passed as `secureCheck`. For example, we couldn't tell whether or not `True` or `False` is passed in during the following:

```
var randomBool = (bool)Console.ReadLine();
var result = CheckThing(a, b, secureCheck: randomBool);
```

I haven't created an analyzer for some time but I believe you would hook into a compilation event and look for `InvocationExpressionSyntax`. You would then look at the arguments passed to this method and decide whether or not to raise an error or warning.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this feature is exists, i would split the function to two:

public bool CheckThingsSecured(){}

[Obsolete()]
public bool CheckThings(){}